# Primary key : query & updates

Tags: cassandra

Little problem here with cassandra. Basically my data has a status (INITIALIZED, PERFORMED, ENDED...), and I have different scheduled tasks that will query this data based on the status with an "IN" clause. So one scheduler will work with the data that is INITIALIZED, one with the PERFORMED, some with both, etc...

Once the data is retrieved, it is processed and the status changes accordingly (INITIALIZED -> PERFORMED -> ENDED).

The problem : in order to be able to use the IN clause, the status has to figure among the primary keys of my table. But when I update the status... it creates a new record in my table, since the UPSERT doesn't find any data with the primary keys given...

How do I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the status column in your primary key columns you can create a [secondary index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html) on the column. However, the `IN` clause is not (yet) supported for secondary index columns. But as you have a very limited number of values to look up you could use equality conditions in your `WHERE` clause and then merge the results client-side?

Beware that using secondary indexes comes at a cost. Check out "[when not to use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html)". In your case these points may apply:

> - On a frequently updated or deleted column. See Problems using an
>     index on a frequently updated or deleted column below.
> - To look for a
>     row in a large partition unless narrowly queried. See Problems using
>     an index to look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly
>     queried below.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's what i'm currently doing. Is it possible to update the value of a primary key though ? I need to do an order by also, so I need to have the field as a primary key, but since the data is supposed to change, it doesn't work. When I update the primary key field, it just creates a new record with the new primary key instead of updating the previous one...

Comment: @ChristopheSchutz, no you cannot update a primary key column. I wonder how you end up with a new row though. If you attempt to execute an `update` statement that attempts to set a primary key column you should receive an error. If you use a `insert`, well, then it is kind of logical that you end up with a new row. You specified a new identity value after all.